# How to exclude Glacier data from input source when reading it via Spark?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-databricks

I'm trying to exclude Glacier data from the input of my Databricks notebook job (Spark). It basically reads parquet data on S3 through AWS Glue Catalog. I already added `excludeStorageClasses` to Glue table properties:

```
|Table Properties | [excludeStorageClasses=[GLACIER], transient_lastDdlTime=1637069663]|
```

but when I read a table it's still trying to read data in Glacier.

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM test_db.users").count()
```

The error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 163, 172.19.249.237, executor 0): java.io.IOException: Failed to read job commit marker: S3AFileStatus{path=s3:...
```

Any ideas how I can make it work or how to exclude Glacier data from input source for Spark job?

Answer (score 0):

additionalOptions = JsonOptions(
Map("excludeStorageClasses" -> List("GLACIER", "DEEP_ARCHIVE")

Comment: how to add this code when reading parquet files?